# I have a table with heaps of columns with different datatype value, but i only want to extract value that is object data type

Tags: python, pandas

I am analyzing data for a company. I have more than 50 columns that have numerical data, however, some of those input are found out to be object type. It most likely is printing mistake but tracking it down manually is very long task. So, I wanted to know how can I extract only those object values from those columns through the whole table.

I have tried using, loc as I thought loc is much convenient to include all the columns.

df2.loc[:,df2.dtypes == object]

Example table:

[image]

However, the result portrayed all the columns that have object value in them. But, the issue is it also portrayed the values that are other type like float. I only want to see the object type.

Comment: What do you mean by "object type", in pandas string columns are also dtype="object".  `df.iloc[:,df.dtypes=object]` is not valid python (SyntaxError) so this is quite confusing.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. So basically, that was my approach to extracting object values from columns that are marked as "object" datatype. Yes i agree, string columns are also dtype = "object". Hence that is what i want to know, that what value is causing my column to be object type and not float. Again, it is possible to do it manually, like tracking down columns that are labelled object datatype and finding out that string value. but its very long process as my table is very big.

Comment: update, my mistake the above code will cause syntaxerror. 
df2.loc[:,df2.dtypes == object]

Comment: could you give a small example of a DataFrame you are looking to fix/address.

Comment: I wish i can, However due to security reasons I cant attach it as it goes against my company's policy.

Comment: However, i added image of example table, see in the image there is string value for my 2 columns. I want to extract just those two string value. thats all. But i dont want to manually add every column one by one.

Comment: When you say "string values" do you mean not digits / not numeric?

Comment: Hello, Sorry for delayed reply, as i was out of my office hours. Yes that is correct when i say string values, it means non numeric :). I'm after non numeric from every   column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to convert these columns to more accurate (numeric) dtypes:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([["1", "2", "a"], ["3", "4", "b"]], columns=["A", "B", "C"])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  a
1  3  4  b

In [13]: df.loc[:, df.dtypes == object]
Out[13]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  a
1  3  4  b

In [14]: for col in  df.columns:
    ...:     df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='ignore')
    ...:

In [15]: df.dtypes
Out[15]:
A     int64
B     int64
C    object
dtype: object
```

Now you can use the dtype lookup either with `.dtypes` or [`.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
In [16]: df.loc[:,df.dtypes == object]
Out[16]:
   C
0  a
1  b

In [17]: df.select_dtypes('object')
Out[17]:
   C
0  a
1  b
```

Comment: Oh wow. Thats really cool idea. ill have a go at it. See what i can find out. But i really appreciate your help, its my first time on stackoverflow, so thank you very much for co operating with me :). Ill let you know how i go :)

Comment: @krijan please "accept" this answer if it helps/works out for you :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/184179 (hope you enjoy Stack Overflow and it's useful!)

Comment: Just had one more question regarding to the same code, say if i want to replace those object value with some int number example: 1. The number can be same for all those object value. Is it possible to do it using for loop or anything ?. If so, could you please assist me on how i can execute that requirement please?. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @krijan If you use pd.to_numeric instead with errors='coerce' then .fillna(number)

Comment: Awesome, Thank you so much, i got it working :). I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Check with `select_dtypes`

```
yourdf=df.select_dtypes(include='object')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I checked with select_dtypes, its providing me with exact same output as my previous code.